# Cucumber Exception: no.of parameters mismatch in Step Definition and gherkin

Tags: cucumber-junit

Tried searching but did not find anything similar. Has anyone encountered this cucumber error before?

> cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Arity mismatch: Step Definition
>   'ExecutionDownloadSteps.scala:50' with pattern [^(\d+) execution
>   report messages are received with the following attributes$] is
>   declared with 0 parameters. However, the gherkin step has 2 arguments

Feature file clause:

```
  When 5 execution report messages are received with the following attributes
     | MsgSeqNum | ExecTransType | PossDupFlag | TransactTime          |
     | 111       | 0             |             | 20140301-00:00:11.001 |
```

Step definition:

```
When( """^(\d+) execution report messages are received with the following attributes$""") {
    (numberOfExecutions: Int, dataTable: DataTable) =>

    //some codes
}
```

Comment: The problem appears more in Linux than Windows. We think it might be caused by the .head method not always picking up the intended definition in Cucumber source code "private def functionParams(f: Any) = f.getClass.getDeclaredMethods.filterNot(_.isBridge).head.getGenericParameterType‌​s". The workaround of this issue is to simplify the method in (//some codes) to only read the datatable so that cucumber can understand the parameters of the function in When step.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in cucumber jvm 1.2.0